# WPF declare use declared xmlns nested namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces

I'm using the following declaration `xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views` and I'm able to use `<v:MyView />`. But what if I want to use with a nested namespace like `MyProject.Views.MyNestedNS`, is there a way I can do it without declaring another `xmlns`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your issue, whatever is in Views that you can excess with your current xmlns. 
As for your question you cant do that without xmlns.
You need to have namespace to gain the excess something.